# Find the min and max value in every month in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

[image]I have an excel having data for entire year.I want to find low and high in every month using some formula or code in c#.I can achieve this by simply applying MIN and MAX formula to each month values by selecting values in column from date 1 to 31 or 30. But i don't want to the repeat the same for each month. Looking for the solution.

Comment: We have no idea of how your file is structured. You have to show us what you have, what you need, what you tried and what you got.

Comment: if you are really asking this for C#, then please show us the code you've got so far (reading from the worksheet - epplus, oledb, excel interop? - representation of the Excel data in C# data structures). the excel-formula tag would suggest to look for answers in the Excel formula expression syntax, or in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by reading out the data using OleDB, something like this might be what you are looking for...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filepath = @"C:\temp\Data.xlsx"; //Location and name of the .xlsx? file
        string connectioninfo = $@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={ filepath };
                                   Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';";

        string query = @"SELECT * FROM [Data$]"; //Worksheet name, if more than one year add a where clause

        List<ExcelDataModel> entries = new List<ExcelDataModel>();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectioninfo))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
                while (reader.Read())
                    entries.Add(new ExcelDataModel { DT = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]),
                                                High = double.Parse(reader[1].ToString()),
                                                Low = double.Parse(reader[2].ToString()) });

            conn.Close();
        }

        var values = entries.GroupBy(x => x.DT.Month).Select(i => new { dt = i.Key, High = i.Max(y => y.High), Low = i.Min(y => y.Low) }).ToList();

        //Do whatever you need with the records
        values.ForEach(month => { Console.WriteLine($"Month: { month.dt } \t Highest: { month.High } \t Lowest: { month.Low }"); });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I also added a class to temporarily store all the rows from the Excel worksheet:

```
public class ExcelDataModel
{
    public DateTime DT { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thankzz Suppe...This is exactly what i was looking for✌️

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`MAXIFS` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883).  Its arguments are the range to search for a maximum, and then sets of values with a criterium.  Some example data:

```
A             B     
01/01/2018    1
21/01/2018    2
10/02/2018    3
02/03/2018    4
22/03/2018    5
11/04/2018    6
```

Then you could use these formula's to calculate a per-month max:

```
C             D
01/01/2018    =MAXIFS(B:B;A:A;">= " & D2;A:A;"<" & EDATE(D2;1))
=EDATE(C2;1)  =MAXIFS(B:B;A:A;">= " & D3;A:A;"<" & EDATE(D3;1))
=EDATE(C3;1)  =MAXIFS(B:B;A:A;">= " & D4;A:A;"<" & EDATE(D4;1))
```

`B:B` is the range searched for the maximum. `A:A;"> " & D4` is the first criteria that says the date must be after the start of the month.  `A:A;"<" & EDATE(D4;1)` is the second criteria that says the date must be before the end of the month.  This calculates as:

```
C             D
01/01/2018    2
01/02/2018    3
01/03/2018    5
```